# Trying to render a sharp 300x300 video

Tags: rendering, video

I have a simple animation that I have made and I cannot seem to get *clear* videos out of at 300px x 300px fpr smartphones, either its the encoding in ffmpeg or the render.  At this point I am unsure. I am confident that when I look at it on the smartphone it doesn't look good.  I am using JPEG format to write from blender to, and webm out of ffmpeg.

Thought:

I am wondering if there is something like a lower limit to rendered frames or compressed video which causes this to be *blurry*.

I can post a link to the video but not now.

The ffmpeg command line (have tried many things) generally has these components in it.  I have seen that with JPEG in ffmpeg maybe '-qscale 1' is used for better quality, om vfx section of the ffmpeg wiki.  I have tried `-pix_fmt yuv420p` also which was recommended on another occasion on the ffmpeg mailing list.  This seemed to work at the time but not in this case.

> When generating a Photo JPEG movie clip there is really only one
>   setting which is relevant - qscale and it should be set to 1. The
>   command line for generating a Photo JPEG movie is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i image-file0%3d.jpg -vb 1M output-file.webm
```

These are settings for the render.

[image: render settings]

this is the render at 300x300

[image: render at 300x300]

And as I mentioned the video is on the net, although I have to edit that link, will do.

Comment: I would never expect a 300x300 image/video to **not** be blurry...that's way to low. Try something like 1024x1024 or 2048x2048 if you want a square.

Comment: I guess this is very ignorant but how do I get it to scale (both file size and viewing size) for a smartphone?  What size should I use?

Comment: 300x300 seems like a very small size. Also, the number of samples you are using seems very low, but it's hard to tell without knowing what kind of image you are rendering. Please [edit] your question and add the image you are trying to render so that we have more elements to help you.

Comment: Believe it or not, but modern smartphones are just as high res as many computer monitors...you need to look up the specs for the device you are targeting. Blender's default 1920x1080 would be a decent res though. BTW If you want different "scaled" sizes you will need to actually make a video of each size using the video sequence editor.

Comment: The video is at http://snaokwrx.com/mobile/Animation.html  it is the mosquito video near the bottom.   Thanks.

Comment: the actual webm is here:  http://snaokwrx.com/mobile/mobile_page_16.webm